# What is the simplest vertical spacer in Outlook (HTML email)?

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-email

What is the simplest vertical spacer in Outlook (and supported everywhere else)?

I have two elements, one on top of the other, both with `display:block`. I would like to space them without wrapping either in a table. I want a spacer that I can reuse anywhere with only simple adjustments to its height. I need to be able to set it to specific pixel heights. I also need to be able to override the height with a media query to make it responsive.

```
<div>test1</div>
<!-- Something here with reliable/succinct height/spacing -->
<div>test2</div>
```

Part of the goal is to avoid splitting things up into table cells every time we need vertical gaps, since that tends to add other complexities even aside from code bloat (bad for email).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found this *consistent*. I use a `div` with `line-height:50px;`. Changing `line-height` predictably/consistently changes the amount of spacing in MS Outlook 2016 on up and every other newer client. Contrary to @Nathan's answer, I do not see any inconsistencies by omiting `font-size`. I am using this in production, and we test in Litmus. I will update this answer if I find an issue. Please let me know if you find a problem.

```
<div style="line-height:50px;">&nbsp;</div>
```

I would love to see more/better solutions to this question. My team and I need a goto solution to become the standard.

Comment: This doesn't work on Outlook Windows desktop 2019 (it does on prior versions). The height is just the height of the standard font. You'd need to add `font-size:50px;` too

Answer (score 2):

The simplest if it's next to the table edges is to add padding to the `<td>` element:

```
<td style="padding:20px 0;">
```

But within a table cell, the simplest is to use a `<p>` element with margin:

```
<p style="margin:20px 0;">
```

Remember to always specify margin top and bottom on the paragraph because there are defaults. I am assuming you already use a `<p>` so it's got content after this. (So, don't use `<p>&nbsp;</p>` like another post says - the height will vary across email clients. And some email clients remove all `<style>` blocks, such as Gmail IMAP.)

In the case that you do not use a block level element and you want something standalone (that would be odd), you could use a `<div>` and specify line-height and font-size:

```
<div style="font-size:30px;line-height:30px;">&nbsp;</div>
```

For comparison, if we were to use a `<p>`, we'd have to write something like this, because `<p>`'s have a default margin that you have to reset, so is slightly more words than a `<div>`:

```
<p style="font-size:30px;line-height:30px;margin:0">&nbsp;</p>
```

(Or `margin:30px 0 0 0;font-size:0;line-height: 0;` which may be arguably 'simpler')

Comment: In my experiments I found `font-size` wasn't necessary using a div with `line-height`.

Comment: Using Litmus, I found OL 2019 didn't work without font-size. However, the earlier versions of OL did work - which version did you test?

Answer (score 1):

In email development, you'll always want to use tables for cross-client consistence. Reset all base styles and use height/width for spacing.

```
<table style="margin: 0;padding: 0;border-spacing: 0;overflow: hidden;background-color: #ffffff;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
    <tbody style="margin: 0;padding: 0;">
        <tr style="font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 100%;margin: 0;padding: 0;">
            <td style="font-size: 0;margin: 0;padding: 0;height: 24px;background-color: #ffffff"></td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I hear that a lot, but my question is about finding a way to NOT use tables because of how much extra code and complexity they are, but also to avoid reformatting only for small gaps.

Comment: If it was possible to avoid, pretty sure devs wouldn't bother with tables, no?
Sounds like your issue is formatting and code complexity, in that case a component workflow like this can help layering out the mess: https://github.com/leemunroe/grunt-email-workflow

Comment: What I've found is that it is possible to avoid. Tables have their purpose, and I use them, but I think it's good to explore if there is an alternative.

Comment: This worked for me in a case where Outlook was ignoring the div in @BBaysinger's answer.

Answer (score 0):

For a application specific spacer you could use:

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

Outlook is quite respectful of common css styling so you could simply use `height` attribute on any element or class I use the `pre` tag in this example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <style>
    pre {
      height:40px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1><%Header%></h1>

  <%Body%>
  
  <div>Line 1</div>
  <pre>&nbsp;</pre>
  <div>Line 2</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I would avoid using margin and padding as its very sporadic across different email clients.

But the most compatible way I've found to maintain spacing across all email clients is sadly still with tables.

Comment: How would you set this to specific pixel heights?

Comment: @BBaysinger added some notes to answer

Comment: Would you not also have to add font-size:0px;line-height:0px to keep the text node from preventing height settings less than the font/line height?

Comment: @BBaysinger I haven't had to. This is a live example I tested by creating a html signature in outlook. The non breaking space is also only necessary in some older mail applications.

Comment: Huh, ok. That's not what I expected, BUT I have to add margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px; or I get a space above and below.

Comment: On a `div` I don't have to set the margins, but I do have to use `font-size:0px;line-height:0px;`.

Comment: Is there an element that wouldn't need either of these?

Comment: Hm, I also found the pre height to be inconsistent in Outlook. I'm using padding-top or bottom to set the height of the div.

Comment: Padding will work in outlook but not in other clients and I'd also reset margin and padding for everything to prevent inconsistancy. I could only imagine you needing to set line-height and font size if your fonts are higher than the height you set for the spacer and you are using `&nbsp;`. You could try max-height also.

Comment: My understanding was that padding had consistent support. I am seeing it behaving 100% consistenly on my div in every client we are testing.

Comment: Yes, supported, but with inconsistant defaults.

Comment: Do inconsistent defaults have any factor on padding that is explicitly set?